# Can not change date/time format

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate, date

I am using UM 20.04 on a persistent install on a pendrive.

When I use dconf-editor and change the custom time format, nothing changes.

**Same** thing happens on a HD installation.

Why did Ubuntu Mate make it so hard to accomplish?

How can I remedy that?

Answer (score 1):

On dconf-editor go:
**com / canonical / indicator / date time** then scroll down to **"time format"** and click on the words to open and change it to **custom**
(near the bottom, turn the use **default** value **off**, under custom value change the value to **custom**.

Comment: This option is not present in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, GNOME version 3.36.8. Where I can find such an option in this configuration?